# PPI or pixels or something else for mediaqueries on HD screens?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm doing some doodling around with responsive design(Finally, right?) and asked myself a question whilst using media queries: "What happens when i use this on a retina screen?".

So i started wondering if it's still proper to use pixels when targetting HD screens. I mean `@media only screen and (min-width: 5 billion px)` seems like a stupid thing to do.

So i wondered what the best practice is. Does the PX scale on HD screens? Or should i use DPI or `device-pixel-ratio` or perhaps something completely different?

My aim is to target pretty much all the screens for a mobile-only page. Pure for practice purposes and seeing for myself what is possible and logical.

My question pretty much is as follows: How can i target HD screens apart from the 'normal' screens in an all-round solution where i can make exceptions for both HD and normal def screens built for 'the future'.

Comment: @dystroy if you plan on changing my title. Please don't make typo's! ;-)

Comment: There're people very intrusive with others' work :(

Comment: Sorry for the typo. But I was afraid your question was going to be closed because vaguely titling "best practices" is a sure way to get closed as not constructive.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for the edit nonetheless ;-)

Comment: I won't dare to edit again but there's a "media-queries" tag...

Comment: Dots per inch (DPI) is **strictly** for print. Pixels per inch (PPI) is more appropriate.

Comment: @Scott that is right. Because a pixel is != a dot.

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify your terms here? High Definition (HD) has a completely different meaning to high pixel density (Apple's "retina" displays, for instance).

Comment: @YiJiang I'm glad you understood what i meant nonetheless ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you use relative units like `em` or `%`.

For example, if everything in your page uses `em`, changing the `font-size` of the body will auto-scale every element proportionally to the font size.

In other words: you should code media-queries for resolution ranges and just adjust the top-most parent font-size (for example the *document body*) depending on the screen width, and the rest of the styles should be outside of these media queries, since a simple change in the font-size will auto-scale the entire page because the `font-size` has changed.

By the way, I doubt `min-width` will ever be "billions of pixels". For now, resoultions don't go beyond 4K in consumer and most professional screens (4096x3113). That is, I don't think you'll need to use a billion-pixels-media-query!

Comment: The billions of pixels is heavily exaggerated i must admit. I am however looking for an all-round solution to target both the lower definition screens(Normal mobile phone for example) and to target HD specifically with it. So what would a proper media query be? min-width 2000 pixels? Or use a different measure. Setting a min-width in percentages isn't going to work obviously.

Comment: @CaptainCarl Ah, when I mean relative units I'm talking about this is what you need to use in your CSS rules in order to have a fully-responsive design.

Comment: @CapitalCarl And about the media-query itself, you should use ranges: min-width 700 - max-width-1000 => this rules, and so on.

Comment: I agree. I'm looking for a specific method though. Something i can use recurringly. Since ranges in pixels seem to not fit the bill(Because i'm pretty sure the screens will only become bigger(resolution-wise))

Comment: @CaptainCarl But again, if you use `em`, you will be adding a new range by just increasing the font-size. I tell you that because I recently did an HTML5 app for Windows 8 and I did this way.

Comment: I see. I'm assuming that Retina screens have a huge font-size to begin with than? And is there documentation to be found what that font-size is specifically?

Comment: @CaptainCarl I mean: you've the ranges in media-queries for just increasing or decreasing the font-size, and small fixes, and the rest of the CSS isn't media-query aware. Then, adding new ranges is as easy as a new media-query, changing the font-size and fixing some small "glitches".

Comment: @CaptainCarl I don't know that. I'm not a Mac guy, but you just need to find the font-size that will make your entire page viewable at this resolution. For example, my experience is that something like `22px`-`24px` will work for FullHD. 4K should be something near to 30px. Just test yourself! (I would do that)

Comment: I may be avoiding the use of setting my own font-size in pixels to begin with by relying on the user-agent setting the appropriate font-size as a basis. It's something i'll have to find out for sure. Reading and discussing this thread i'm leaning towards EM a lot as a fitting solution. (The pages don't have to be identical obviously, a  few pixels off are no big deal ;) )

Comment: @CaptainCarl `em` is an unit relative to the font-size of the parent container. You should set the font-size, independently to the one set by the browser, because your design could be absolutely destroyed if the user sets a custom font-size in the browser settings. It's just my opinion, eh!

Answer (score 4):

Well, 160 DPI is the baseline for screen PX density - since it is 1:1 screen PX to device PX. The Retina display is 2:1 screen PX to device PX which is 320-330 DPI.

So, if you are only aiming to make it work for Retina

```
min-device-pixel-ratio: 2;
min-resolution: 192dpi;
```

Should be fine. However, Android for example supports a range of devices with a different DPI; including 160 DPI ("mdpi"), 240 DPI ("hdpi"), 320 DPI ("xhdpi"), and between.

Edit: Added example below.

```
@media
only screen and ( -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25 ),
only screen and ( min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25 ), 
only screen and ( -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25 / 1 ),
only screen and ( min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25 ),
only screen and ( min-resolution: 200dpi ),
only screen and ( min-resolution: 1.25dppx ) {}
```

Comment: This is only supported on WebKit for now: http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/@media_%28-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio%29

Comment: Please give him proper links to browser support. Opera:  http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/@media_%28-o-min-device-pixel-ratio%29 - Firefox: http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/@media_%28min--moz-device-pixel-ratio%29 my answer is widely supported.

Comment: I did a small search and I found that. I was wrong, the world isn't perfect!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer And webkit makes up for more than %80 of browsers that this kind of detection would be useful.

Comment: @Petah The WebKit nightmare! I was an Opera user and fan, and I'm very sad that there will be no choice in browser market. Firefox is decreasing its marketshare, IE10 is nice... It seems that WebKit will rule the Web world!

Comment: @Petah I hope so, because you know what happens when a single vendor rules the entire market...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer you get competition?

Comment: @Petah Yeah, I'm developing a true W3C, full of standards Web browser that will kill WebKit........ ;)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Never kill the future; Google, and Apple cannot help that every one else is too slow to keep up with the newest technologies.

Comment: Fan boy @JimmyvanBeele thinks only Google/Apple pushes web standards  forward. Microsoft is one of the top contributors to the W3C.

Comment: @Petah It is 2013, who still cares about W3C?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the standard practice of setting the browser scaling via meta viewport (or for non-WindowsPhone8 IE10, @ms-viewport) width = device-width.

In that case the CSS "px" units you reference in your width/height media queries will very roughly correspond to one physical pixel on a 160ppi screen regardless of it being high PPI or not. In reality it can range from ~130ppi to ~180ppi.

So if you are ok with this inaccuracy in the physical screen sizes that will match your width/height "px" media queries, go right ahead. Just make sure you are enabling the hardware developer defined "css layout px" to "physical pixel" scaling available on pretty much every modern mobile device in one form or another.

Note: It is also possible to rely on some clever javascript to glean more accurate PPI readings from clients. I currently do this in order to acquire a unified PPI value across both mobile and desktop, a task which can get messy (think desktop "Page Zoom" vs "Viewport Zoom" vs "System Zoom") considering that currently all non-IE browsers have similar issues stuck on their bug-trackers indicating a severe architectural schism between mobile and desktop in relation to pixel scaling/zoom/ratio/whatever